# Am I correct about .toFixed() and decimals?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, math, tofixed

I gave an example of using `.tofixed()` with math, functions, and arrays, to a beginner coder friend who has been reviewing these topics in his class.

```js
const bananaX = 9;
const bananaY = 2.9768;
bananaArray = [bananaX , bananaY];


console.log("X before array = " + bananaX);
console.log("Y before array = " + bananaY + '\n')
console.log("X,Y after array = " + bananaArray + '\n')
console.log("Value of X in array: " + bananaArray[0]+ '\n')
console.log("Value of Y in array: " + bananaArray[1]+ '\n')


function bananaDivision (bananaArray){
console.log("Value of X after function = " + bananaX);
console.log("Value of Y after function = " + bananaY + '\n')

let bananaDivided = Math.abs(bananaX/bananaY );
console.log (`X divided by Y = + ${bananaDivided}` + '\n')
let bananaFixed = bananaDivided.toFixed(2);
console.log("After using .toFixed(2) : " + bananaFixed + '\n');
};

bananaDivision();
```

They were understanding and following along no problem.
Then they asked me - "What if we put a decimal in the .toFixed ?"
So I ran:

```js
const bananaX = 9;
const bananaY = 2.9768;
bananaArray = [bananaX , bananaY];


console.log("X before array = " + bananaX);
console.log("Y before array = " + bananaY + '\n')
console.log("X,Y after array = " + bananaArray + '\n')
console.log("Value of X in array: " + bananaArray[0]+ '\n')
console.log("Value of Y in array: " + bananaArray[1]+ '\n')

function bananaDivision (bananaArray){
console.log("Value of X after function = " + bananaX);
console.log("Value of Y after function = " + bananaY + '\n')

let bananaDivided = Math.abs(bananaX/bananaY );
console.log (`X divided by Y = + ${bananaDivided}` + '\n')
let bananaFixed = bananaDivided.toFixed(2);
let bananaFixed1 = bananaDivided.toFixed(.69420);
let bananaFixed2 = bananaDivided.toFixed(1.69420);
console.log("After using .toFixed(2) : " + bananaFixed + '\n');
console.log("After using .toFixed(.69420) : " + bananaFixed1 + '\n');
console.log("After using .toFixed(1.69420) : " + bananaFixed2 + '\n');
};

bananaDivision();
```

I explained it as that `.toFixed` is looking at the first number within the `()` and that the decimals are ignored.

Am I correct? For my own curiousity, is there a crazy way to break `.toFixed()` so that it actually uses decimals? I'm experimenting atm but wanted to know if someone already figured that out.

Comment: have you looked at some docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed?

Comment: @SuperDJ I don't see an explanation there for what happens if the argument has a fractional part.

Comment: Are you referring to
" ```toFixed()``` returns a string representation of ```numObj``` **that does not use exponential notation** and has exactly ```digits``` digits after the decimal place"    ? @SuperDJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I explained it as that .toFixed is looking at the first number within the () and that the decimals are ignored.

This would be correct. That is essentially what happens.

For full correctness, the input of `toFixed()` will be converted to an integer. The specification states that the argument must first be converted to a number - `NaN` will be converted to a zero. Numbers with a fractional part will be rounded down.

Which means that if you pass any number, you essentially get the integer part of it.

It also means that non-numbers can be used:

```js
const n = 3;

console.log(n.toFixed("1e1")); // 1e1 scientific notation for 10
```

Comment: Thanks you very much! I oversimplified because I partially forgot. lol

Comment: @Banana you were correct. I just added the extra information about conversion partially for completeness and also because otherwise the answer would be too short. The vast majority of time `.toFixed()` will be called with a number as argument, so your explanation makes sense. The details are not that important, except in extreme edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

You're close, since toFixed() expects an integer it will handle converting decimal numbers before doing anything else. It uses toIntegerOrInfinity() to do that, which itself uses floor() so the number is always rounded down.

Most of Javascript handles type conversion implicitly, so it's something you should really understand well if you don't want to run into problems. There's a free book series that explains that concept and a lot of other important Javascript knowledge very well, it's called [You Don't Know JS Yet](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/README.md).

Answer (score 0):

just a demo how `.tofixed` works !!!!!!

```js
function roundFloat(x, digits) {

const arr = x.toString().split(".")
  if (arr.length < 2) {
    return x
  }else if(arr[1] === ""){
  return arr[0]
  }else if(digits < 1){
  return arr[0]
  }

  const st = parseInt(x.toString().split(".")[1]);



  let add = false;
  const rudgt = digits
  const fX = parseInt(st.toString().split("")[rudgt]);

  fX > 5 ? add = true : add = false


  nFloat = parseInt(st.toString().split("").slice(0, rudgt).join(""))
  if (add) {
    nFloat += 1
  }
  const repeat0 = (() => {
    if (rudgt - st.toString().length < 0) {
      return 0
    }
    return rudgt - st.toString().length
  })()
  const output = x.toString().split(".")[0] + "." + nFloat.toString() + "0".repeat(repeat0);
  
  return output
}

console.log(roundFloat(1.200, 2))
```